# How to flatten to dataframe a list with NULL?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to convert this list:

income <- list(list(2016L, "hello", NULL))

into a tibble, transforming all `NULL` into `NA`:

```
  X2016L X.hello. NA.
1   2016    hello  NA
```

This is the solution I have, but I wondered if there was a more straightforward way using `as_tibble`

```
tibble(year = map_dbl(income,1),
       geo= map_chr(income,2),
       income = map_chr(income,3, .default = NA))
```

For instance something like:

```
> l %>% as.data.frame()
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
> l %>% as_tibble()
Error: Column 1 must be named
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a list `L` from `income[[1]]` and replace each zero length component with `NA`. Then set the component names (since tibbles must have column names) and convert to tibble.

```
library(tibble)

L <- income[[1]]
L[lengths(L) == 0] <- NA
names(L) <- c("year", "geo", "income")
as.tibble(L)

## # A tibble: 1 x 3
##       a b     c    
##   <int> <chr> <lgl>
## 1  2016 hello NA
```

or using pipes:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

income %>% 
  first %>%
  replace(lengths(.) == 0, NA) %>% 
  setNames(c("year", "geo", "income")) %>% 
  as.tibble
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create the list**

```r
income <- list(list(2016L, "hello", NULL))
```

which gives us

```r
income

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 2016

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "hello"

[[1]][[3]]
NULL
```

**2. Coerce list into a tibble**

```r
income_tibble <- as_tibble(t(sapply(income,c)))
```

which gives us

```r
income_tibble

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  V1        V2        V3    
  <list>    <list>    <list>
1 <int [1]> <chr [1]> <NULL>
```

**3. Replace all NULL as NA**

```r
income_tibble[income_tibble == ""] <- NA
```

which **should** give us

```r
income_tibble

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  V1        V2        V3       
  <list>    <list>    <list>   
1 <int [1]> <chr [1]> <lgl [1]>
```

*Comment: above code is how it actually **should** work. On my machine, however, I can only get it to the expected result with the following code:*

```r
income_tibble[income_tibble == "NULL"] <- NA
```

Maybe somebody else can chip in on the why?

Comment: Because NULL is not an empty string, and in this case "NULL" is just a string, not probably what was wanted in the original code.  NULL has a specific meaning in R and it is a characteristic of an object not individual values within a vector.